# C# camera acquisition program crashing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, camera, crash

I'm developing a C# library using Visual Studio 10 for acquiring frames and recording video from four cameras. The windows form that will include the library has to be compiled at 32 bit (even if the final machine has windows 7 64 bit). Compiling the library at 32 bit and running it for about 1 hour will crush the application with the following error:

```
Firma problema:
Nome evento problema:            BEX
Nome applicazione:               S102.exe
Versione applicazione:           1.0.2015.619
Timestamp applicazione:          55963958
Nome modulo con errori:          clr.dll
Versione modulo con errori:      4.0.30319.34209
Timestamp modulo con errori:     5348961e
Offset eccezione:                0000e233
Codice eccezione:                c0000409
Dati eccezione:                  00000000
Versione SO:                     6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
ID impostazioni locali:          1040
Informazioni aggiuntive 1:       bae0
Ulteriori informazioni 2:        bae094b824883e215fdbc3ee2b394585
Ulteriori informazioni 3:        4415
Ulteriori informazioni 4:        441563ebf8308b83ce61454e88cff59c

Leggere l'informativa sulla privacy online:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0410

Se l'informativa sulla privacy online non è disponibile, leggere quella offline:
C:\Windows\system32\it-IT\erofflps.txt
```

I've done a lot of test to check out the problem. Until now I've managed to run the application for more than 9 hours consecutively only under the following conditions:

1. the windows form including the library is compiled at 64 bit
2. the application is ran under visual studio (button 'start debug F5') no matter if the form is compiled at 32 or 64 bit.

The library is compiled as 'Any CPU'. I've checked mutiple times my code to find if there is some memory leaking or some bad code but I didn't find anything. It is more than two weeks that I'm stuck with this problem. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you very much!

**Update:**

I have excluded from the code the part in charge of:

- converting the RAW image to Bitmap
- visualizing the converted image

having thus an application grabbing continuosly RAW images from 4 cameras (without vizualizing). This code ran for 14 hours without crashing. I can say that the problem is residing in this part of code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(grabResult.Width, grabResult.Height,PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
// Lock the bits of the bitmap.
BitmapData bmpData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);
// Place the pointer to the buffer of the bitmap.
converter.OutputPixelFormat = PixelType.BGRA8packed;
IntPtr ptrBmp = bmpData.Scan0;
converter.Convert(ptrBmp, bmpData.Stride * bitmap.Height, grabResult);   //Exception handling TODO
bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);

// Assign a temporary variable to dispose the bitmap after assigning the new bitmap to the display control.
Bitmap bitmapOld = pictureBox.Image as Bitmap;
// Provide the display control with the new bitmap. This action automatically updates the display.
if(pictureBox!=null) pictureBox.Image = bitmap;
if (bitmapOld != null)
{
// Dispose the bitmap.
bitmapOld.Dispose();
}
```

Does anybody see anything suspicious in this code? Thank you!

Comment: 0xC0000409 is STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN ("The system detected an overrun of a stack-based buffer in this application. This overrun could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this application.") Do you use unmanaged code in your library? Or stackalloc?

Comment: Hello, no I don't use stackalloc. What do you mean with 'unmanaged code'? Object not disposed or memory not freed? I checked my code and i didn't see anything suspicious. Furthermore, I can't explain why the code works if compiled at 64 bit or ran under VS but it doesn't work in the other cases

Comment: With unmanaged code I mean that maybe your library calls other dlls that are natives (for example they are written in C/C++)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The libraries called by my library are native for C# therefore they should be suitable for my purposes

Comment: Hello, I've realized that the libraries that i call are actually written in C++ therefore I said a  wrong thing claiming that I don't use unmanaged code

Comment: Probably the x86 version of the library contains bugs that corrupts the stack. Do you have control over the source code of the library?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But why then under the Visual Studio 10 debugger the code could run for 9 hours without having errors?